# Change Vuetify checkbox label color?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify checkbox and i have set up a label but the label has a `color:rgba(0,0,0.54)` style applied to it which is quite light and i am trying to change the color to `rgba:(0,0,0)` but i am not able to target the `.v-label theme--light` class.

Check out this simple [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/PoPBajM)

Check out this sample below:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {};
  }
});
```

```css
.v-label theme--light {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-checkbox label="myLabel"></v-checkbox>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you want to change `.v-label theme--light` to `.v-label.theme--light`?

Comment: whoops!! you can add this as an answer and i'll accept it. thank you.

Comment: glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.v-label theme--light` to `.v-label.theme--light` and it should work.

Comment: quick question though, how can i still target it with scoped styles. using `scoped` messes it up. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class `black-label` to `v-checkbox`

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-checkbox label="myLabel" class="black-label"></v-checkbox>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and then update scoped style like:

```
<style scoped>
.black-label label {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
</style>
```

**Demo:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {};
  }
});
```

```css
.black-label label {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.18/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@1.0.18/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-checkbox label="myLabel" class="black-label"></v-checkbox>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help and yes i ended up taking this route. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use v-label and ::v-deep
if you want change anything in vuetify, you should use ::v-deep.
example: `
::v-deep .v-label

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `scss` in your app, you can override vuetify styles with `v-deep`

```
.v-input--checkbox::v-deep {
  .v-label {
    color: rgba:(0,0,0);
  }
}
```